# XQuery - Order By not correctly ordering

Tags: xquery, flwor

Order by clause does not seem to be working. Do I have the correct xquery query?

```
for $record in doc('XQuery.xml')/dataroot/RecentIndices_solarFlux 
where $record/Month = 1 or
        $record/Month = 2
order by $record/Geomagnetic_Smoothed_Ap
return $record
```

The output I'm getting is something like this:

-1, 10.5, 11.6, 5, 8.7

I am using Stylus Studio X14 Release 2 XML Enterprise Suite.

Comment: Please provide some example data, the output you get using this data and the output you'd like to achieve. Something seems to be very wrong as the whole `$record` should be printed, you only get some numbers. By the way, you could also write `where $record/Month = (1, 2)` exploiting XQuery's set comprehension of comparison operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem was because I was using decimal numbers, so I surrounded the path in order by with xs:decimal( exp. ).